I'm getting an error while building my Next.js app. I used Next.js and Sanity to create my portfolio

I am currently facing an issue while trying to finalize the build of my portfolio. Specifically, I am working on creating a production build to host my portfolio online. However, I keep encountering an error that is preventing me from completing this process. Below is the screenshot of the error message displayed in the terminal:

There's not enough info from your post to help you with a specific answer but based on the error message, here are some possible ways to fix the error referenced from the Nextjs docs:

Use Next.js 13 (or higher) and the App Router, which allows colocation of pages and other files (e.g. components, styles, tests, etc)

Make sure to move any non-pages out of the pages folder
Check for any code that assumes a prop is available, even when it might not be.

Set default values for all dynamic pages' props (avoid undefined, use null instead so it can be serialized)

Check for any out of date modules that you might be relying on.

Make sure your component handles fallback if it is enabled in getStaticPaths. Fallback docs.

Make sure you are not trying to export (output: 'export' or next export) pages that have server-side rendering enabled getServerSideProps

If necessary, you can disable server-side rendering for a specific component that may be attempting to use browser APIs like window


